# SRILM Installation for Kaldi

Tags: linux, makefile, grep, kaldi

I'm in the process of training Kaldi using [Kaldi for Dummies](https://kaldi-asr.org/doc/kaldi_for_dummies.html) and when I try to install SRILM, I get the following error:

```
./misc/doc/Opt.man
./misc/doc/Opt.doc
./install_srilm.sh: line 63: common/Makefile.machine.$mtype: ambiguous redirect
./install_srilm.sh: line 65: common/Makefile.machine.$mtype: ambiguous redirect
grep: common/Makefile.machine.could: No such file or directory
grep: not: No such file or directory
grep: determine: No such file or directory
grep: MACHINE_TYPE: No such file or directory
./install_srilm.sh: line 69: common/Makefile.machine.$mtype: ambiguous redirect
grep: common/Makefile.machine.could: No such file or directory
grep: not: No such file or directory
grep: determine: No such file or directory
grep: MACHINE_TYPE: No such file or directory
rm -f DONE
(find bin/* lib/* */bin/* */obj/* */src/test */test/output */test/logs -type d -print -prune ; \
ls build* go.build-*; \
find me htk contrib lm/src/test flm/src/test lattice/src/test dstruct/src/test utils/src/fsmtest zlib/orig common/COMPILE-HOSTS include bin -print; \
find . \( -name Makefile.site.\* -o -name "*.~[0-9]*" -o -name ".#*" -o -name Dependencies.\* -o -name core -o -name "core.[0-9]*" -o -name \*.3rdparty -o -name .gdb_history -o -name out.\* -o -name "*[._]pure[._]*" -o -type l -o -name RCS -o -name CVS -o -name .cvsignore -o -name GZ.files \) -print) | \
sed 's,^\./,,' > ../EXCLUDE
find: ‘bin/*’: No such file or directory
find: ‘lib/*’: No such file or directory
find: ‘*/bin/*’: No such file or directory
find: ‘*/obj/*’: No such file or directory
find: ‘*/src/test’: No such file or directory
find: ‘*/test/output’: No such file or directory
find: ‘*/test/logs’: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'build*': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'go.build-*': No such file or directory
find: ‘me’: No such file or directory
find: ‘htk’: No such file or directory
find: ‘contrib’: No such file or directory
find: ‘lm/src/test’: No such file or directory
find: ‘flm/src/test’: No such file or directory
find: ‘lattice/src/test’: No such file or directory
find: ‘dstruct/src/test’: No such file or directory
find: ‘utils/src/fsmtest’: No such file or directory
find: ‘zlib/orig’: No such file or directory
find: ‘common/COMPILE-HOSTS’: No such file or directory
find: ‘include’: No such file or directory
find: ‘bin’: No such file or directory
fgrep -l /bin/sh bin/* > ../EXCLUDE-shell
grep: bin/*: No such file or directory
fgrep -l /bin/sh bin/* > ../EXCLUDE-shell
grep: bin/*: No such file or directory
fgrep -l /bin/sh bin/* > ../EXCLUDE-shell
grep: bin/*: No such file or directory
/home/parallels/kaldi/tools/srilm/common/Makefile.common.variables:108: MACHINE_TYPE: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target 'MACHINE_TYPE'.  Stop.
```

I downloaded the srilm.tar.gz file and renamed it etc. but when I run sudo ./install_srilm.sh it doesn't work.
I'm not sure how to fix this - any ideas?

Comment: Clearly the `install_srilm.sh` file wanted to set the variable `mtype` to the type of the machine (whatever that means for this config), but it failed and it set that variable to the value `could not determine MACHINE_TYPE` instead.  That causes the failures in grep.  As to why `mtype` could not be set, there's no way we can help with that given the information provided you'll have to look at the script to see how it's set.  Also you can try running `/bin/sh -x install_srilm.sh` and see what operations are done to set `mtype`.

Answer (score 0):

The extra packages are usually done by

```
cd kaldi/tools
extras/install_SRILM.sh
```

make sure kaldi is properly compiled in accordance with your g++ and GCC version.